# MySQL CLI client change socket location

Tags: mysql

I have one app server and several DB servers. In DB servers I have installed the entire MySQL server package, but in app server, I only installed MySQL client package to make it able to connect to MySQL server which resides at DB servers. Since I am using InnoDB cluster, so in my app server I have installed and bootstrap-ed the MySQL router. 
Now I want to connect to MySQL server via MySQL router. I have to issue either one MySQL command below:
`mysql -uroot -p'password' -h127.0.0.1 -P6446`
`mysql -uroot -p'password' -P6446 --protocol=tcp`

I have to specify the port, which is ok in this case since MySQL router has configured different port to access different db (Read-Write db or Read-Only db). What I mind about is I have to specify the `-h127.0.0.1` or `--protocol=tcp` to force it to use TCP connection instead of socket. If I don't specify it, I will get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My goal is to get rid of specifying host/protocol in every connection. Where does `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` come from? Is it MySQL default socket location? the actual socket location I configure in `my.cnf` at DB server for `[client]` group is `/opt/mysql/mysql.sock`. And the socket location configured in router is `socket=/etc/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock`. I have tested if I specify the socket location with `--socket` to the one configured in router, it will work without specifying the host and protocol as TCP, I don't even need to specify host, as based on different socket, router know which db you are connecting (there is another socket `mysqlro.sock` which is for read-only db). How to change the default socket location since MySQL client package doesn't come with `my.cnf` (or it actually does?). If above is not possible, can I force MySQL Client connection via TCP by default?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sock%';`

Comment: Do you editing the correct `my.cnf` file? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: I didn't edit any `my.cnf` in this case, coz server side config is all fine. I can see that the socket is configured properly at `/opt/mysql/mysql.sock` by issuing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sock%';` command in MySQL server. My question is, from client side, how can I change the default socket location? I can't even find `my.cnf` at client side.

Comment: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`  will see such line: `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: or search for socket word in mysql folder:  `grep -R "socket" /etc/mysql`

Comment: @Newbie Depending on the OS you are using the configuration file might be at `~/my.cnf`. Have you tried adding the options in that file under the `[client]` or `[mysql]` section?

Comment: @num8er no directory `/etc/mysql` in my app server

Comment: @Progman OS is Red Hat 7, the `[client]` and `[mysql]` section is added properly in server side (db server), client side (app server) couldn't find `my.cnf` at all.

Answer (score 2):

To setup configurations for a client program (on a client host, in your case most likely the app server) you have to create a new file in your users directory called `~/.my.cnf`, as described in [4.2.2.2 Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html). Use this file to add default settings for the `mysql` application by adding a `[mysql]` section. As an example, when you run

```
$ mysql --print-defaults
```

it will show the following (example) output:

```
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--loose-default-auth=mysql_native_password
--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
--character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
--loose-default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

*(new lines added for readability)*

Add the following lines to your new `~/.my.cnf` file:

```
[mysql]
socket=/tmp/example
```

From now on the following default settings will be used:

```
$ mysql --print-defaults
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--loose-default-auth=mysql_native_password
--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
--character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
--loose-default-character-set=utf8mb4
--socket=/tmp/example
```

For testing purposes, when you call `mysql` you will get the following error message (as expected):

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/example' (2)
```

In your case you might want to add the line `host=127.0.0.1` so it will use the given hostname as you would with `-h127.0.0.1`. You might also add the `port` setting in this file as well.

Answer (score 0):

My web server is REHL 8.6. It has only mysqlrouter and mysql client installed. There is NO mysql server installed.

In my **/etc/my.cnf** file there is only one line `!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d`, meaning all files from this config directory are included. If it isn't there, you can add this line, and create such a directory.

So I go to this directory **/etc/my.cnf.d** and find only one file **/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf**. If it isn't there, you can create such a file.

I edit this file and under `[client]` section, I insert line `socket=/my/own/path/to/mysql.sock`. Now the `mysql` command line will connect without specifying socket.

Hope it works.